# Theorem symbol with ntheorem

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, theorems, ntheorem

Why am I now getting a theorem symbol with this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    linecolor=blue,
    ntheorem=true
}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Some Definition]
This is a definition with an equation
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4,
\end{equation*}
and some text.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

What I get is this

[image]

but I want a small symbol in the lower right corner of the definition, denoting that the definition is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the `ntheorem` package with the option `thmmarks`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    linecolor=blue,
    ntheorem=true
}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Some Definition]
This is a definition with an equation
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4,
\end{equation*}
and some text.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might need `\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}`

Comment: @thomaskeefe If there is a reason for using the option, why not. Otherwise the manual recommends not to use it.